# HierarchicalUriComponents - it's not recognized when trying to import it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web

HierarchicalUriComponents - it's not recognized when trying to import it - I'm using spring boot version 2.1.13 and Spring-web 5.1.14

Answer (score 0):

Yes you cant import since `HierarchicalUriComponents` is not a `public` class and  is accessible only by classes in the same package

```
final class HierarchicalUriComponents extends UriComponents { ... }
```

It is more of an internal implementation which you can check in `UriComponentsBuilder.build()` class as to how it is used.

```
public UriComponents build() {
    return build(false);
}

public UriComponents build(boolean encoded) {
    return buildInternal(encoded ?
            EncodingHint.FULLY_ENCODED :
            this.encodeTemplate ? EncodingHint.ENCODE_TEMPLATE : EncodingHint.NONE);
}
private UriComponents buildInternal(EncodingHint hint) {
    UriComponents result;
    if (this.ssp != null) {
        result = new OpaqueUriComponents(this.scheme, this.ssp, this.fragment);
    }
    else {
        HierarchicalUriComponents uric = new HierarchicalUriComponents(this.scheme, this.fragment,
                this.userInfo, this.host, this.port, this.pathBuilder.build(), this.queryParams,
        // Other logic 

        return result;
    }
```